# java.lang.Exception: ServletConfig has not been initialized

Tags: java, spring, servlets

i have a problem is:

> java.lang.Exception: ServletConfig has not been initialized

I searched for it nearly 2 days but i did not have a solution for me. Every one had said that
**super.init(config)** must be used. I have tried this, but there is nothing change for me.

My init method;

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    super.init(config);

    AppServiceServlet service = new AppServiceServlet();
    try {
        service.getir();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AutoCheckStatus.autoCheckStatus(600000);
}
```

and my AppServiceServlet;

```
    public List<SswAppServiceDto> getir() throws Exception {
    try {
        final WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(this
                .getServletContext());
        setiAppServiceBusinessManager((IAppServiceBusinessManager) context.getBean(BEAN_ADI));

        List<SswAppService> result = getiAppServiceBusinessManager().getir();

        List<SswAppServiceDto> list = DtoConverter.convertSswAppServiceDto(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            AppService appService = new AppService();
            appService.setServiceName(result.get(i).getName());
            appService.setUid(result.get(i).getServiceUid());
            appService.setHost(result.get(i).getHost());
            appService.setPort((int) result.get(i).getPort());
            SystemConfiguration.appServiceList.put(appService.getUid(), appService);
        }
        return list;

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown in this line;

```
          final WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
```

in AppServiceServlet and says:

> java.lang.Exception: ServletConfig has not been initialized.

Pls help.

Comment: please paste the full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call:

```
AppServiceServlet service = new AppServiceServlet();
```

Instantiates a servlet instance via `new`, which circumvents the normal, container managed creation of a servlet. As such, critical class variables (for example, the servlet config) don't get properly initialized.

Later on, you are making a call to `getServletContext`, which simply redirects to `getServletConfig().getServletContext()`, but because the servlet configuration was never completed you get an exception.

Infact, calling `new` on a servlet the way you are is non-compliant with the specification - servlets are supposed to be maintained by the web app container. The proper way to launch a startup servlet is either via configuration in your web.xml file, or via annotation.

Comment: I put the method which is in AppServiceServlet to InitServlet and it works. Thank you very much. You are awsome man.

Comment: @köksalfp Can you describe on what you did to get this to work?  I'm trying to get this to work for a Mockito test case, and running into the same issue.

Comment: @Marcus make sure you call `super.init(config);` in your Servlet init method

Comment: What's in the config?